# Why is the the background image url name different from the local image name ? And same for other resources like fonts etc set in css using url()

Tags: html, css, angular

I wanted to preload the background-image in my angular app, only to find that the image is rendered by a different name than the local image. Which made me figure out that all the resources loaded using url in the css are reneder by a name which is dfferent from their local name.

So when the background image is `background-image: url('../img/home-bg.jpg');` , it gets renderd in production as

```
http://www.beinghealer.com/home-bg.1c0835203511d0a3.jpg
```

Similarly `url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2")` gets rendered as `http://www.beinghealer.com/fa-solid-900.9fe4f614c5426b17.woff2`

I have two questions:

1. Why does `home-bg.jpg` change to `home-bg.1c0835203511d0a3.jpg`, and `fa-solid-900.woff2` change to `fa-solid-900.9fe4f614c5426b17.woff2` ?
2. How can I preload these resources ? I tried to preload image using `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="assets/img/home-bg.jpg">` inside head tag, but it preloads `http://www.beinghealer.com/home-bg.jpg`, which is not same as the url which gets rendered in the website!

The website client code is written in Angular 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you put your resources into your "src" folder. They get optimized and output-hashed, the purpose being to destroy the browser cache if there is one.

The good practice here is to put your resources into the "assets" folder : they won't get renamed. In your style, you can now access them with

```css
background-image: url('assets/img/home-bg.jpg');
```

As for the preloading, I recommend you switch to Angular v15 (the latest one) and use `ngSrc="your image source"` instead of the usual "src".

Comment: `home-bg.jpg` image is not in "src" folder, but in `assets/img/home-bg.jpg`
Since it is called from `assets/css/style.css`, so it is accessed using `url('../img/home-bg.jpg')`

Comment: In that case, in `angular.json`, replace "outputHashing" which should have the value "all", to "bundles". And not sure about the path, so try both ways !

Comment: Indeed "outputHashing" has been set to "all". Let me try with "bundles"!

Comment: It did remove the hashing of image, thanks! I am accepting your answer since you appropriately explained why the hashing happens and how to stop it!

But just found that this does not really solve the preloading problem coz the preloaded image is `http://www.beinghealer.com/assets/img/home-bg.jpg`, and the rendered background image is `http://www.beinghealer.com/home-bg.jpg`

Comment: That would be because of the path, as explained previously. Did you happen to test it ?

Comment: Yes I tested it and by setting "outputHashing" to "bundles" it fixed the name of the image by removing the hash, but the image paths of rendered image and the preloaded image are different.
Reg your previous point about path: The resources had always been in the "asset" folder and not directly in the "src". The only thing I can think of is that the link preloading is done in the "index.html" which is in "src" folder.

Comment: Image rendered using "src" in "image" tag (`<img src="assets/img/xx.jpeg" />`) is rendered with full path (`http://www.beinghealer.com/assets/img/xx.jpg`). Issue is only with "background-image", which is why preload does not stop background-image from reloading when rendered.

Comment: Interestingly, when I make another copy if home-bg.jpg in the "src" folder, and  then when i preload image in "index.html" using <link rel="preload" as="image" href="home-bg.jpg">, then the preloading works fine for the background-image in "assets"!!!